# Will .net MVC3 bring easier integration for alternative view engines?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, spark-view-engine, viewengine, nhaml

As you might know .MVC3 brings an alternative view engine named Razor.
As I understand in order to make this possible MS has put more effort in making integration of alternative view engines easier.

Will this have any impact for other view engines (nHaml, Spark ...)?
What I'm mostly interested in is tooling integration (syntax highlighting, code completion 
etc).

Answer (score 1):

> What I'm mostly interested in is tooling integration (syntax highlighting, code completion etc).

That has nothing to do with MVC. It's related to writing Visual Studio plugins that recognize the file extension being opened and add syntax highlighting and Intellisense. So MVC 3 won't bring anything new in terms of tooling support for third party view engines (other than of course the syntax highlighting and the Intellisense for the Razor view engine built by Microsoft).

Comment: MVC 3 RC is out and now includes Intellisense for Razor: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/09/announcing-the-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate.aspx

Comment: @Nelson, I think he is asking about Intellisense in third party view engines such as NHaml and Spark. We all know that Razor would eventually get Intellisense (after all it's Microsoft baby)

Comment: Yes, that's why I didn't post my own answer.  `MVC 3 won't bring anything new ` sounded like the future, but I just wanted to point out it's already out.

Comment: @Nelson, until a product hits RTM I consider it still in the future :-)

Comment: Maybe the source for the Razor plugins will also be available and provide a usefull example for 3rd party providers?

Answer (score 0):

As Darin pointed out MVC 3 will not bring intellisense for 3rd party view engines (ultimately it's their responsibility to write the necessary VS plugins)

However, MVC 3 does make it easier to plug 3rd party view engine templates into the Add New Project and Add View dialogs.